# Strange knockout js select option binding issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Does anybody have a minute to take a look at a puzzling problem I'm having with Knockout JS and binding select lists?

The person's favourite color should be selected in the list by calling `value: favColorId` in the select list, rather than with the function-based call of `value: favColorId()`, something very strange is going on here, I've never used () in the past, it's also causing some other weird issues where it won't recall the value into the span (so changing the selected item does nothing).. I have tried recreating a simple sample as best I can demonstrating the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/goneale/ph8Jw/

Comment: Hm... When I tested your fiddle, it was opposite. It worked with `favColorId`, but not `favColorId()`

Comment: The brackets on favColorId are not needed. KO will call ko.utils.unwrapObservable()

Comment: Is the bottom `<select/>`s selecting for you? They are not using the brackets, and none are selected for me.

Comment: Take the brackets off the top one's `value:` statement as well and no values across all drop downs are selected.

Comment: Yeah the second example works for me

Comment: @marvc1, can you press "Fork" and send me example with them selecting without the brackets?

Comment: This is a fork with both examples working http://jsfiddle.net/X4XNE/. I only removed the brackets from favColorId.

Comment: I don't know what browser you are using, but for me, in your example, all `<select>` boxes say "choose.." and nothing is selected? I tried your example in FF and Chrome :(

Comment: NilsH, what results are you getting?

Comment: Here FF20, Chrome26 your fiddle working with `value: favColorId` and NOT working with `value: favColorId()` by the way to correct usage should be `value: favColorId` without the `()`

Comment: This is just freaky..... what is going on :( Bad dev day with the gods against me... when you guys change the selected option, is the span favColorId next to the select updating as well? you can see in my screenshot I only receive selected options on using bracketed version!  http://i.imgur.com/JkqQmlS.png

Comment: Using no brackets, I have nothing selecting by default! http://i.imgur.com/HLAGgZl.png

Comment: So you guys are not receiving the same results with your code setup the same as in my screenshot? How is this possible :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have included my `mapDictToArray()` function but it simply converts a
>   javascript object into a key-value JS array. I wouldn't think that is
>   contributing to the problem.

Actually, that was part of the problem. The function returns a JavaScript array, not an observable array and therefor can't be used properly by Knockout. I've made the following changes to your code:

```
// The "mapDictToArray" makes a normal JS array, not a ko.observableArray();
// You can't simply "merge" a JS array with an observableArray(); you'll need
// some extra functionality for that: ko.utils.arrayPushAll()
// viewModel.colors(mapDictToArray(dict));
ko.utils.arrayPushAll(viewModel.colors(), mapDictToArray(dict));

// Apply the bindings *after* you've added the contents to the "colors" observable, in order to
// get the correct selected value
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

That should do the trick (with the correct HTML without the `()` )!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph8Jw/26/).

**UPDATE**

I thought about my solution, but something wasn't correct. The only thing that was correct, was the part that you need to apply the bindings *after* you've added the contents of the colors observable. [This is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph8Jw/31/), with that part moved down.

This works *in your case*, but you'll need to use the `arrayPushAll` method when there is already data inside the `observableArray`. This method merges, while you overwrite it when not using it ([example with data inside the observable](http://jsfiddle.net/ph8Jw/30/)).

Comment: THANK YOU MarcoK, I will take a good look at this sample.. I actually ripped out mapDictToArray() from question and jsfiddle because I didn't think it was contributing. I also found this one without mapDictToArray (which is actually mapping an array to dict, silly me) isn't working also. http://jsfiddle.net/goneale/ph8Jw/28/ But all might be revealed in your code. Thanks again.

Comment: Fantastic and thanks again. Didn't know about `ko.utils.arrayPushAll`. I will start merging this into my real project and see if it all works now :)

Comment: Glad to help you out! I did update my answer a little bit with more info. Hope it worked out in your real project!

Comment: You wouldn't believe what my problem turned out to be, you got me on the right track thinking about orders and precedence.. It wasn't that my mapping occured after my `applyBindings` call, but that I had two tasks to perform, 1) got my page form data JSON (including setting what should be the correct options per person in the drop down list) then the 2) retrieved all the drop down list options; I was assigning the person's drop down list option BEFORE populating the actual drop down list options! So it was binding effectively on to an empty list, THEN populate the list :\ Thanks for helping!

Comment: and for the important info re. `arrayPushAll()`, will keep that in mind for merge jobs.

Comment: Hi @MarcoK, I have another one, regarding KO.validation I could really use some help with if you're up for it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229775/validate-observables-within-a-collection-using-knockout-validation